# Cosa si chiede più frequentemente in banca per acquistare una casa: un "prestito ipotecario" oppure un "mutuo"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, word-meaning

Immagino che queste siano parole di uso quotidiano: per acquistare un appartamento, ad esempio, oggi è frequente di andare in banca per chiedere un prestito. Comunque, non riesco a capire quando si usi "prestito ipotecario" e quando "mutuo" nel linguaggio comune.

Quale di queste espressioni è usata più frequentemente dagli italiani quando vanno in banca perché hanno bisogno di soldi per acquistare un appartamento?

Comment: Questa domanda riguarda forse più l'ambito finanziario che quello linguistico... Mutatis mutandis è come se chiedessi che differenza c'è tra un platano e un pioppo: ti saprebbe rispondere meglio un botanico che un linguista.

Comment: Può essere, ma quando gli italiani vanno in banca perché hanno bisogno di soldi per acquistare un appartamento cosa chiedono più frequentemente un mutuo oppure un prestito ipotecario?

Comment: Concordo nel non considerare questa una domanda sulla lingua italiana.

Comment: In Italia si parla di mutuo, che poi normalmente è un mutuo ipotecario. Ma effettivamente questa domanda sembra off topic.

Comment: Ho cambiato leggermente il senso della mia domanda: non era la mia intenzione richiedere dettagli tecnici relativi al mondo delle finanze. Spero che adesso non sembri "off topic".

Comment: Tenete conto che, in altre lingue, ci sono parole simile a "ipoteca" e "ipotecario", ma forse non ci sia una parola simile a "mutuo" nel vocabolario finanziario di uso comune (non mi riferisco al vocabolario tecnico dell'ambito finanziario). Ad esempio, in spagnolo e in catalano si usano il sostantivo "hipoteca" e gli aggettivi "hipotecario" in spagnolo e "hipotecari" in catalano. Tali parole simile possono avere un uso e un senso nel linguaggio comune diverso da quello che si fa in italiano.

Comment: Rispondo in forma di commento perché non porto fonti: sento sempre parlare di “mutuo” e non ho mai sentito la locuzione “prestito ipotecario” nel senso di cui parli, ma: 1) non sono addentro all'ambiente, e 2) ho capito che cosa chiedi, ma non sempre l'uso quotidiano di termini tecnici corrisponde al loro vero significato. Per esempio, spesso si usano un po' a casaccio i termini “denuncia” e “querela”, che invece sono due cose ben distinte e ognuna con una sua precisa definizione. Spero che questa non-risposta possa essere di qualche aiuto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si dice accendere/aprire/chiedere/fare un mutuo.

Si può parlare anche di "chiedere un prestito per (comprare) la casa" (solo "prestito", *senza* "ipotecario" a seguire: nessuno direbbe "devo chiedere un prestito ipotecario" in una normale conversazione).

Infine, perdona la digressione, l'unico termine simile a ipotecario che venga effettivamente utilizzato nel linguaggio comune è "ipoteca". Esempi: 
"Mi serve un prestito, quindi penso di ipotecare la casa" o "Sono costretto a mettere/far mettere/aprire un'ipoteca sulla casa"

Comment: Capisco (grazie mille!), ma ho ancora una piccola domanda sull'uso che hai indicato della parola "ipoteca". Quando qualcuno afferma di "ipotecare la casa" o di "mettere un'ipoteca sulla casa", tale azione si può fare soltanto su una casa di proprietà di quella persona? Cioè, una persona non può mettere un'ipoteca su una casa che non è ancora di sua proprietà, ma che vuole acquistare?

Comment: Esistono più tipi di ipoteca (vd. wikipedia), ma nel caso più semplice, il nostro, solo il proprietario può far mettere un'ipoteca sulla casa (cioè chiede soldi e in garanzia della restituzione offre la sua casa).

Comment: Vedo che l'uso quotidiano in italiano di "ipoteca" e "ipotecario" è molto diverso dell'uso di parole simile in spagnolo o in catalano (grazie mille della risposta!).